# React DID NOT update components after update list state (by hook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-hooks

When use useState hook to store list of object (ex. [{ a:1 }, { a:2 }]), If I change list's element(object)'s content, react **DO NOT** update component.

---

For example in below code,

If I press first button, first h1 component's content will be 24. **BUT** even though I press first button, first h1 component component **DO NOT** update.

If I press second button after press first button, component **DO** update.

```js
const [tempList, setTempList] = useState([
  { a: 1 },
  { a: 2 }
])


return (
  <div>
    {
      tempList.map((item, idx) => {
        return <h1>{item.a}</h1>
      })
    }
    <button onClick={() => {
      let temp = tempList;
      temp[0]['a'] = 24
      setTempList(temp)
    }}>modify list</button>
    <button onClick={() => {setTempList(...tempList, {a: 3})}}>insert list</button>
  </div>
)
```

---

I **already** used useReducer hook. But it is not solution.
How Can I update component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React re-render the component when the state or props change. And it determines that the state has changed by only looking at the memory address of the state.

In the callback of the first button, by declaring the variable `temp`, you are only creating a shallow copy of the `tempList` array. Therefore, even after modifying the first object, the id of the array does not change and react does not know that the state have been changed.

And also, by putting a callback in the `setState` function, you can always have a fresh reference to the current state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0);
setState(state+1) <-- the state can be stale
setState(state=>state+1) <-- increment is guaranteed
```

Try building an another array:

```
<button onClick={()=>{
  setTempList(tempList=>tempList.map((item,ind)=>{
    if(ind===0){
      return {a:24};
    }
    else{
      return item;
    }
  })
}}>modify list</button>
```

You had a syntax error in the second callback. In addition to the fix, I recommend again to put a callback function to the `setTempList` function.

```
<button onClick={() => {
  setTempList(tempList=>[...tempList, {a: 3}])
}}>insert list</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be updating same reference of object instead of pushing a new object. Try this -

```
const [tempList, setTempList] = useState([
  { a: 1 },
  { a: 2 }
])


return (
  <div>
    {
      tempList.map((item, idx) => {
        return <h1>{item.a}</h1>
      })
    }
    <button onClick={() => {
      let temp = [...tempList];
      temp[0] = { a: 24 };
      setTempList(temp)
    }}>modify list</button>
    <button onClick={() => {setTempList(...tempList, {a: 3})}}>insert list</button>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: OH you use [...templist] for deep copy like JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(templist))
Is react do re-render after deep copy? I will do that. THX

Comment: Umm.. I cannot understand difference of 'Deep copy' and 'create new object'. Can you explain about it? If you have no more time, that's OK. THX too much